# add_menu_page() for more than one user role

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, add-menu-page

If I add a custom page to the wordpress backend menu via

```
add_menu_page('My Custom Page', 'My Custom page', 'editor', 'custom_page','add_custom_page','dashicons-admin-comments',8);
```

only a user with editor privileges can see the page in its menu. How can I make this menu entry also available for users with administrator privileges? Have I to use *add_menu_page()* for every user role seperately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a look at [Codex page for `add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/)...

Third param is:

> **$capability** *(string)* (Required) The capability required for this menu
>   to be displayed to the user.

And later on in Notes section:

> This function takes a ‘capability’ (see Roles and Capabilities) which
>   will be used to determine whether or not a page is included in the
>   menu. The function which is hooked in to handle the output of the page
>   must check that the user has the required ‘capability’ as well.

As you can see, you should use capability (for example `manage_options`, `publish_posts`) and not user role (`editor`, `subscriber`) as that param.

So if you'll pass `publish_pages` as third param, only Editor, Administrator, and Super Admin will get access to that page.

Here you can find list of [default capabilities for default user roles](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

Comment: Can I pass multiple capabilities?